# UIButton.titleLabel resists font changes to a smaller font

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton

I have a UI button that I want to change the font for.  Before attempting to change the font, I run the button code in the debugger, and print out the font for the title label:

```
po acceptButton.titleLabel.font
<UICTFont: 0xc61ae70> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt
```

I then execute the line of code:

```
[acceptButton.titleLabel setFont:[LNSocialAppearance fontHelveticaNeueRegularWithSize:10]];
```

LNSocialAppearance is just a convenience method which immediately responds:

```
 return [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue Regular" size: points];
```

Afterwards, I print out the titleLabel's font again:

```
po acceptButton.titleLabel.font
<UICTFont: 0xc390f50> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

What's going on here?  Why did the font only go down by 1?  Is there a minimum font allowed on UIButton, and does this have anything to do with dynamic type?

UPDATE:  As per Omer's suggestion, using setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]] works correctly.  But I'd rather not be forced to use the system font; is there some limitation on the Helvetica Neue font family?  And if so, how do I find out what the minimum/maximum font sizes would be?

I'm not entirely sure that's the case though, as it's setting the font size to 17 no matter what number I give it - even if I give it 20, it doesn't get any larger either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the string used for the font; "Helvetica Neue Regular" has been replaced with "Helvetica Neue" as well as other font weights ("HelveticaNeue-Light" for example) and these are scaling down properly.  Watch the spacing in those strings carefully!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `label.minimumFontSize = 10;`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to have any impact on it; it still gets set to 17 afterwards.  Note that it seems to be getting set to 17 regardless of whatever number I try to set it to; setting it to 20 also results in 17.

Comment: Did you try getting LNSocialAppereance out of the way and setting the font directly? Also have you tried using the system font?

Comment: I have tried setting the font directly; it didn't make any difference.    System font of size 12 does work, although I'd rather be able to have any font rather than just the system font.  It's an improvement, at least.

Comment: Can you try with a different custom font please?